# React Native Stripe SDK crashes on real device build during await presentPaymentSheet(): java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I am developing an app using React Native and the Stripe SDK. The app works fine in `Expo Go` and `development build`, however, when I try to build it on a real device, the app crashes. Below is the code related to the error and the error log.

```js
import { useStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';
const { initPaymentSheet, presentPaymentSheet, confirmPaymentSheetPayment } = useStripe();

useEffect(() => {
    if (isInactive(user)) {
      initializePayment().catch(err => {
        console.error("Failed to initialize payment", err);
      });
    }
  }, [subscriptionSecret, customerId])

const initializePayment = async (): Promise<void> => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      if (subscriptionSecret) {
        const { error } = await initPaymentSheet({
          customerId: customerId,
          paymentIntentClientSecret: subscriptionSecret,
          merchantDisplayName: 'a',
          customFlow: true, 
        });
        if (error) {
          console.log('Failed to initialize payment sheet', error);
          alert('支払いの初期化エラーが発生しました。もう一度やり直してください。');
        } else {
          console.log('initialize succeeded');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', e);
      alert('予期せぬエラーが発生しました。');
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

const handlePay = async (): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      if (!paymentIntentClientSecret) return;
      const { error } = await presentPaymentSheet();

      if (error) {
        console.error('Payment failed', error);
        alert('Payment error occurred, please try again.');
        return;
      } else {
        console.log('Payment succeeded');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      return;
    } 
    try {
      setIsLoading(true)
      const { error: confirmError } = await confirmPaymentSheetPayment();
      console.log('error', confirmError);
      if (confirmError) {
        Alert.alert(`error  code: ${confirmError.code}`, confirmError.message);
      } else {
        // (payment success handling code)
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
      alert('Payment error occurred, please try again.');
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  at com.stripe.android.paymentsheet.flowcontroller.DefaultFlowController.presentPaymentOptions (DefaultFlowController.kt:225)
  at com.reactnativestripesdk.PaymentSheetFragment.present (PaymentSheetFragment.kt:157)
  at com.reactnativestripesdk.StripeSdkModule.presentPaymentSheet (StripeSdkModule.kt:176)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
  at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:907)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:784)
```

package.json

```
- "expo": "~48.0.21"
- "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.23.3"
- "react-native": "0.71.14",
```

I am particularly puzzled by the error message java.lang.IllegalStateException occurring at the DefaultFlowController.presentPaymentOptions method call during the await presentPaymentSheet() call. The card input does not appear and the app crashes instead. Any ideas on the cause and solution to this error? Also, this error does not occur in Expo Go, and only happens in the real device build. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you [`initPaymentSheet()`](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet#react-native-collect-payment-details) before `presentPaymentSheet()`?

Comment: Yes. I do.
```const { error } = await initPaymentSheet({
          customerId: customerId,
          paymentIntentClientSecret: subscriptionSecret,
          merchantDisplayName: 'a',
          customFlow: true,
```

Comment: Can you make sure, in release this is falling true condition? if (isInactive(user)) {

Comment: @user42195 is the if condition falling in true in release?

Answer (score 0):

1. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet#stripe-initialization I Think its important that the stripe provider is the outer one
2. Where do you fetch your `subscriptionSecret`? also you should be sure that
   `initializePayment` is called before `handlePay` a way to do that is an async function that first awaits `initialize payment` and then awaits the `handlePay`
3. why do you call `confirmPaymentSheetPayment` when `presentPaymentSheet`
   will return if the payment fails or not.